# Append only if item doesn't exists in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 select boxes,
one for country,  another for cities and another one for radius around a city.

I want whatever the user choses  to appear in a div before sending and saving all data in db.

I'm trying to make this work, but I dont know why I'm having strange results.
It does nothing!, but if I remove the " ! " it kinda works for the first one , but then i get duplicates again. 
I dont understand what am i doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
var citySet = new Array;
function appendCity(){                  

    if(!$.inArray($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text(),citySet)){                            

        $("#cityContainer").append($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>"); 
        citySet.push($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text());  

    }

}
```

Any light shed will be gratfull

Comment: You know that its too damn difficult to read unformatted code, right?

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `=== -1` or `< 0`

```
var citySet = new Array;

function appendCity() {
    if ($.inArray($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text(), citySet) === -1) {
        $("#cityContainer").append($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>");
        citySet.push($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text());
    }
}
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(citySet.indexOf($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text()) < 0){
    $("#cityContainer").append($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>"); 
    citySet.push($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this:**

```
var citySet = new Array;
function appendCity(){                  

        if($.inArray($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text(),citySet)===-1){                            

            $("#cityContainer").append($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text() + "<br>"); 
            citySet.push($("#businessCityTarget option:selected").text());  

        }

    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: if `!==-1` is true, it means element is present in array. Here as Op wants its opposite